# Encontrar array e imprimir error si lo tiene repetido con find

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Necesito encontrar el valor de un array y eliminarlo. Me han dicho que lo puedo hacer con .find(). La verdad no he podido relizar el codigo correcto en typescript.
Tengo todos los valores de los array dentro de un for y dentro de ese mismo for, debo de encontrar los valores de array duplicados y sacar error.

```
repeatCostCenter() {
for (let found = 0; found < this.costCenterOptions.length; found++) {
  let element = this.costCenterOptions[found];
  this.costCenterOptions.find()
}
```

Pienso en...
Si encuentro que el valor del array[1] es igual al valor del array[0], me imprima un mensaje diciendo que tengo dos valores iguales.

Tengo 5 Array. Cada array, tiene 1 objeto. Cada objeto tiene un id. Quiero encontrar ese id.
Quiero encontrar el id de un objeto, despues de encontrar ese id, buscar si ese id esta duplicado o repetido dentro de otro array.

El id esta dentro de lo siguiente

```
 setCostCenters(costCenters: GetCostCenterRS[]) {
this.costCenters = costCenters;
this.costCenterOptions = this.costCenters.map(
    costCenter => {
        const option: SelectItem = {
            label: costCenter.CostCenterName,
            value: costCenter.id,
        };
        return option;
    }
);
```

}

El id seria costCenterOption[array].value.

Como hago para encontrar ese id y mirar si esta repetido con otros array?

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de valores tienes en el array? ¿Qué tamaño tiene dicho array?

Comment: Tiene 5 array unidimensionales. Estoy llamando un servicio de un backend a los array. Lo que se trae al array son objetos.

Comment: Entonces lo que quiero, es que como dentro de un solo array hay una especie de "tabla con datos (varios datos)"; Entonces voy a llamar los id solamente de cada array

Comment: Un array con 5 arrays o con cinco objetos? Buscar arrays repetidos es más complejo

Comment: 5 Array.
Cada array, tiene 1 objeto. Cada objeto tiene un id. Quiero encontrar ese id

Comment: Y al encontrar el id, buscar si esta duplicado o repetido con otros id de otros array y si esta repetido, imprimir error

Comment: Jhonatan, por favor agrega esta descripción del problema que pusiste en comentarios en la pregunta, presionando [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/167017/edit). Por otro lado, mientras esperas una respuesta, te recomiendo leer como usar `.find()`, por el código que muestras.

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo desde "*El id seria `costCenterOption[array].value`*", porque el resto es bastante confuso, y considerando que quieras ver si ese `value` esta repetido en otra posición de ***costCenterOption*** podrías hacer lo siguiente:

***Aclaraciones:***

> A modo de ejemplo lo hice con una lista de ID directamente, pero como
>   tienes un objeto dentro del array que posee el ID, debes hacer
>   `currentValue.value` para la comparación y el `console.log`, el resto de la lógica sigue
>   igual.

```js
var costCenterOption = [2,10,4,2,6,10,5,8,4,3,8];
this.costCenterOption.sort();
this.costCenterOption.forEach(function (currentValue, index, array) {
    if(index !== array.length && currentValue === array[index+1]){
            console.log(currentValue  + ' es un ID repetido');
    }
});
```

### Explicación:

> Primero ordenas la lista de ID, al ser numéricos los repetidos
>   quedaran uno al lado del otro, luego solo debes ver que ID tiene en la
>   posición siguiente su igual.